# It gets to the if statements and stops working, what am I doing worng (new to java)

Tags: java, logic

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaMovies {
      Scanner det = new Scanner(System.in);
      int age = det.nextInt();

public static void main(String[] args){
    calculator();


}


public static void calculator(){

Scanner det = new Scanner(System.in);

    String rMovie = "Attack of the nerds";
    String mMovie = "Nerd lyfe";
    String pgMovie = "Nerd adventures";
    String gMovie = "Nerd playtime";
    System.out.println("These are the movies that are playing this weekend"
            + rMovie
            + mMovie
            + pgMovie
            + gMovie);
    System.out.println("Please input your age");
   int age = det.nextInt();


System.out.print("Input the movie you wish to see:");
    String x = det.nextLine();                             //Program ends here...

    if(x.equals("Attack of the nerds") & age > 17){
        System.out.println("You can see Attack of the nerds");

    }else if(x.equals("Attack of the nerds") & age < 18){
        System.out.println("You can see attack of the nerds!");

    }if(x.equals("Nerd lyfe")& age > 15){
        System.out.println("You can see Nerd lyfe");

    }else if(x.equals("Nerd lyfe")& age < 16){
        System.out.println("You can not see Nerd lyfe");

    }if (x.equals("Nerd adventures")& age > 10){
        System.out.println("You can see Nerd adventures");

    }else if(x.equals("Nerd adventures")& age < 11){
        System.out.println("You can not see Nerd adventures");

    }if(x.equals("Nerd playtime")& age > 5){
        System.out.println("You can see Nerd playtime");

    }else if(x.equals("Nerd playtime")& age < 6){
        System.out.println("You can not see Nerd playtime");


    }
}
}
```

Everything is alright up to the start of the if statements, what can I do to fix this?

Console output(using netbeans)
run:
These are the movies that are playing this weekendAttack of the nerdsNerd lyfeNerd adventuresNerd playtime
Please input your age
14
Input the movie you wish to see:BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `nextInt` doesn't use up the whole line.  If you type `32` when prompted for your age, `nextInt` will consume the `3` and `2` characters, but there is still a *newline* character remaining in the input string.  Then, when you call `nextLine`, the effect is to return everything that's remaining in the current line, up to the next newline.  Since the current line still has a newline character, this results in `String x = det.nextLine()` setting `x` to an empty string.

Try `det.nextLine();` before prompting for the movie.  (You don't need to assign it to a variable; just throw the result away.)  That will cause the scanner to consume the newline, so that the next `nextLine()` will get another line of input.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I am only starting to learn java so sorry if that was an easy question.

Comment: @user3808741 This trips up a lot of people.  No need to apologize.